# How do I add link to another page [Django 3.0]? Reverse not found

Tags: python, django, anchor

I'm trying to add a link to `blogDetails.html` on the main page, but using the `{% url '...' %}` template tag is raising a *Reverse not found* exception.

**index.html**

```html
<a href="{% url 'blogDetails' %}">O blogu</a>
```

**urls.py**

```py
path('blogDetails/', views.BlogDetailsPageView.as_view(), name='blogDetails'),
```

**views.py**

```py
class BlogDetailsPageView(TemplateView): 
    template_name = 'blog/blogDetails.html'
```

**main urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
]
```

This is the error I get:

```py
Reverse for 'blogDetails' not found. 'blogDetails' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

What on earth is going on here? All help appreciated.

Comment: Is your app's urls.py in your main urls.py ?

Comment: @marlonjd added main urls.py

Comment: `url 'blog:blogDetails'`

Comment: Don't forget to set `app_name = 'blog'` in the app's urls.py, or the namespacing will fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `urlpatterns` you use `namespace='blog'`. Looking at [the django documentation for the `{% url %}` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url), it says:

> If you’d like to retrieve a namespaced URL, specify the fully qualified name:
>
> ```
> {% url 'myapp:view-name' %}
> ```

If you add the **blog** namespace to your templatetag call, it should work:

```
<a href="{% url 'blog:blogDetails' %}">O blogu</a>
```