# Adding a link to another page in Django(3.1) (NoReverseMatch)

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, django-urls

I'm trying to add a link to another page on my index page, but when I use `{% url 'blog:BlogAbout' %}` I get:

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:'blog' is not a registered namespace
```

index.html:

```
<a href="{% url 'blog:BlogAbout' %}">About Me</a>
```

blog.urls.py:

```
path('about/', views.about, name="BlogAbout"),
```

blog.views.py:

```
def about(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/about.html')
```

urls.py:

```
path('', include('blog.urls')),
```

The question is almost familiar to this: [How do I add link to another page [Django 3.0]? Reverse not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59274477/how-do-i-add-link-to-another-page-django-3-0-reverse-not-found)

I'm doing it like there but I still get an error.
What is the right way to add the link?

Comment: Share the `urls.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `blog:` prefix is if you specify an `app_name = 'blog'` in the `urls.py`. If you did not do that, then there is no "namespace", and therefore the url is simply:

```
<a href="{% url 'BlogAbout' %}">About Me</a>
```

If you want to use a namespace, you specify this in the `urls.py` with:

```
app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    path('about/', views.about, name='BlogAbout'),
    # …,
]
```

or, you can specify this with the `namespace=…` parameter in the [**`include(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#include):

```
    path('', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
```

then you specify this with:

```
<a href="{% url 'blog:BlogAbout' %}">About Me</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! But when I want to use a namespace, where do I need to specify that in urls.py?

Comment: @Luca: you specify this with `app_name = ...` in the `urls.py`.